# How to represent order content in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

I am creating a pizza shipping website, and I need to represent the orders and their content somewhere in the database.

The problem is, I have absolutely no idea how to store items and their quantities.

My first thought is to create an order_content table, which contains the order's id as a foreign key, and has two extra columns : item id and quantity.

Another problem : I have multiple types of items : pizzas, drinks, extras etc... So id's aren't unique across categories. I can't just say, for example in order_content *item_id 1, quantity 1*, because item_id 1 can mean drink with id 1, pizza with id 1, etc...

Another big problem : I have a custom pizza which can have 3 to 6 custom ingredients. I have ingredients in a table with their unique id's... How can I represent this custom pizza in orders ?

Thank you

PS : I am fairly a beginner in SQL - Relational databases

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? [ask] [Help]

Comment: Right now you are effectively asking for us to write a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & you show no research effort.] [Re homework.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck/unsure. Dozens of published academic information modelling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf & html. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a schema that you should experiment with and modify to suit your needs.

> ```
> create table clients(
>   id serial,
>   name varchar(25) not null,
>   email varchar(25) not null,
>   telephone varchar(25),
>   constraint pk_clients_id primary key (id),
>   constraint uq_clients_email unique(email)
>   );
> create table items(
>   id serial,
>   name varchar(25),
>   price decimal(5,2),
>   constraint pk_items_id primary key (id) 
>   );
> create table orders(
>   id serial,
>   client_id int,
>   constraint pk_orders_id primary key (id),
>   constraint fk_orders_client foreign key (client_id) references clients(id)
>   );
> create table toppings(
>   id serial, 
>   name varchar(25) not null,
>   constraint pk_topping primary key (id));
> create table order_details(
>   order_id int, 
>   item_id int,
>   quantity int,
>   topping_1 int,
>   topping_2 int,
>   topping_3 int,
>   topping_4 int,   
>   topping_5 int,
>   topping_6 int,
>   constraint fk_order_details_order_id foreign key (order_id) references orders(id),
>   constraint fk_custom_pizza_id foreign key (item_id) references items(id),
>   constraint pk_order_details_order_item_ids primary key(order_id, item_id)
>   );
> ```

> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into clients (name, email, telephone) values ('Andrew','andrew@gmail.com','0123456789');
> insert into items (name, price) values('custom pizza','20.00'),('1.5 litre coca-cola',5);
> insert into toppings (name) values('mozzarella'),('parma ham'),('mushrooms'),('olives'),('red peppers'),('salmon');
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

2 rows affected

> 

6 rows affected

> 

> ```
> with order_number as
> (insert into orders (client_id) values (1)
> returning id)
> insert into order_details 
> select order_number.id,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6 from order_number
> union all
> select order_number.id,2,1,null,null,null,null,null,null from order_number;
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select 
> c.id,
> c.name,
> o.id order_number,
> od.item_id,
> i.name,
> i.price,
> od.quantity * i.price as line_total,
> t1.name topping_1,
> t2.name topping_2,
> t3.name topping_3,
> t4.name topping_4,
> t5.name topping_5,
> t6.name topping_6
> from clients c
> left join orders o on c.id = o.client_id
> left join order_details od on o.id = od.order_id
> left join items i on od.item_id = i.id
> left join toppings t1 on od.topping_1 = t1.id
> left join toppings t2 on od.topping_2 = t2.id
> left join toppings t3 on od.topping_3 = t3.id
> left join toppings t4 on od.topping_4 = t4.id
> left join toppings t5 on od.topping_5 = t5.id
> left join toppings t6 on od.topping_6 = t6.id
> ```

> ```
> id | name   | order_number | item_id | name                | price | line_total | topping_1  | topping_2 | topping_3 | topping_4 | topping_5   | topping_6
> -: | :----- | -----------: | ------: | :------------------ | ----: | ---------: | :--------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :---------- | :--------
>  1 | Andrew |            1 |       1 | custom pizza        | 20.00 |      20.00 | mozzarella | parma ham | mushrooms | olives    | red peppers | salmon   
>  1 | Andrew |            1 |       2 | 1.5 litre coca-cola |  5.00 |       5.00 | null       | null      | null      | null      | null        | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=15163c6a7cea2c5d79218020957cfe81)*

Answer (score 1):

In general, storage systems of shopping sites are using relations between an order and an order line.

You could organize your DB like this and answer your problems

| order | order_line | product | ingredient | ingredient_for_product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | order_id | product_id | ingredient_id | ingredient_id |
| ... | quantity | current_unit_price | name | order_line_id |
|  | **unit_price** | product_type | additional_price | quantity |
|  | product_id |  |  |  |

**product** is an abstract concept that holds all sold products by your company. If you need to be more precise, you can either add fields that will be completed depending on the value of **product_type**  or create another table with a one-on-one relationship with the product table.

you have a **unit_price** in the order_line table and a **current_unit_price** in the product table.

This has two uses :

1. if you change the price of your product a posteriori, you will still keep the price your customer paid
2. it allows you to store a price which is different from your registered "current_unit_price". For example, adding the value of supplementary ingredients

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the *fact table* and *dimension table* definitions. Once this concept is understood it will be clear for you the the order table will be a *fact table*, and tables such as ingredients will be a *dimension table*.